# I really need an advice with multiple checkboxes + textboxes in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to make a mobile repair website and I am currently stuck a little. From my tiny admin panel I can add a "brand", a "service" e.g. repair a display, and add a phone model. The problem is with adding a phone model. Just stay with me. Right now I am adding services with price attached, so there can be "Fix display for 100", "Fix display for 200" etc. So after adding a lot of "services" you can add a phone model and check the services withing a checkbox list. This uses too much space, so I'm stuck with the problem of having just the service names, and inputing the price to the service later (when i add a phone model)

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM Brand");
echo '<select class="form-control"name="brandid">'; 
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row3['id'].'">'.$row3['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
Name: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="modelname">
Image: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="modelimage"></br>
Service List: <?php echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><tr><th>*</th><th>Service Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>';
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,servicename, serviceprice FROM service");
while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) { 
   echo '<tr><td><lable>'; 
   echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row4['id'].'" id="'.$row4['id'].'" name="servicelist[]"></td><td>'.$row4['servicename'].' </td><td>'.$row4['serviceprice']; 
   echo '</lable></td></tr>'; 
} 
echo '</table>';
```

$row4['serviceprice']; - I want to replace this with a text box. But not sure how to send the values. I'm just lost. Should I make a mysql table named Price now? With priceid, serviceid and modelid? And then somehow join all of this when showing the model? Really lost.
Would like to hear a tip from someone more expirienced than me. Thank you.
Alex.

Edit:

I got to this point:

```
$pricelist=$_POST['price'];
foreach ($pricelist as $k){
$sql="INSERT INTO Price (modelname, serviceid, price)
VALUES ('$name', '$SERVICE_ID_OF_ONE_SERVICE', '$k')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

need to put in service id for each price from an array that i get from a from of checkboxes. should i have foreach within foreach?

Comment: Looking at the code it looks your stuck a bit more than just little.

Answer (score 0):

Im not i fully understand what you want to do, but if you want to send data from your website using a text box to your php file you can do it as follows.

```
<form action="yourphpfile" method="post">
<input type= "text" name="price" placeholder="enter your price"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

your php

```
$price= $_POST["price"]
```

now the variable $price holds the price that you sent. If your php is in the same file as your html you leave action as "" or just write the filename.

Comment: http://188.138.234.178/wellfix/index2.php this is what i'm making. maybe it will be easier to understand. the "Add model" form. I need to somehow tie the checked box with the textbox.

Comment: If you want to display the value of the text box you can  concatenate the $_POST["price"]. If not can you explain exactly what you want to do with the data?